# XML Parser with jSoup - No output?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, jsoup

This code sends some details to an openvas server and receives XML in return. I am trying to take the 'id=' string from the XML string. It seems to be working (ie no errors) but won't output contents from the 'id' String. Its almost like nothing is in it.

I tried adding a random string to 'id' - this outputs fine to the jTextField6.

Can anyone see my issue?? Thanks!

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
          String TargIP = jTextField1.getText(); // Get IP Address
          String TargName = jTextField5.getText(); // Get Target Name
          String Vag = "8d32ad99-ac84-4fdc-b196-2b379f861def";
          String Lob = "";

  final String dosCommand = "cmd /c omp -u admin -w admin --xml=\"<create_target><name>" + TargName + "</name><hosts>" + TargIP + "</hosts></create_target>\"";

  final String location = "C:\\";

try {
     final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        dosCommand + " " + location);
     final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
     int ch;
     while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char)ch);
       Lob = String.valueOf((char)ch);
       jTextArea2.append(Lob);



     }
     String id = Jsoup.parse(Lob).getAllElements().attr("id"); // This may be the issue

       jTextField6.setText(id);



  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

String Lob is as follows:

```
<create_target_response id="b4c8de55-94d8-4e08-b20e-955f97a714f1" status_text="OK, resource created" status="201"></create_target_response>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Jsoup.parse(jTextArea2)` -  Lob is the last single char.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its always the little things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lob` will contain just one character, being the last one read from the stream. Here's how I would do it, FWIW:

```
StringBuilder fullResponse = new StringBuilder();
while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char)ch);
    fullResponse.append(String.valueOf((char)ch));
 }
 jTextArea2.append(fullResponse.toString());
 String id = Jsoup.parse(fullResponse.toString()).getAllElements().attr("id");
```

*Edit* - Updated with StringBuilder as per @Pshemo.

Comment: Side note: while `+=` is easier to understand it is better to use separate `StringBuilder` to append new characters to it.

Comment: Quite right, thanks, one never knows how long the response will be, and it would be a shame to kill all those string kittens.